# Email Open Rate Tracker - Differences in email client

Tags: php, email, tracking

I've implemented a very common approach to email open rate tracking using a 1x1px transparent image:

```
<img src="https://myserver/trackresponse?source=1&action=1"
 style="border:0;width:1px;height:1px;" alt="" />
```

And the php code to track response and return the image looks like this:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
(Record response on DB)....
$im=imagecreatefrompng("/images/pixel.png");
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

On viewing the email the request for the image is executed (I know this as the the response is recorded on the DB).

Although Gmail (webmail and iphone app) and even Outlook.live.com displays the email correctly (as in you can't see the tracking pixel), the Windows mail app (Windows 10) displays this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: And you are sure that you get a request when the mail is opened in the Windows mail app as well?

Comment: yes, I've just rechecked.

Comment: And do you get a different result, if you point the `img` element to the static image file instead (with the same CSS applied)? Maybe it has an issue with the image itself, or the (display) size of 1*1 pixel …?

Comment: I'll try it now...

Comment: It works fine as a static image, just not as a php request

Comment: Then check what other headers besides Content-Type the response contains when you request the “static” image from your server, and try and mimic those in your dynamic output. Maybe it’s something simple like a Content-Length.

Comment: And btw., going through the whole imagecreatefrompng/ imagepng/ imagedestroy ordeal is not really necessary here. You already have valid binary PNG data in your image file, so it is enough to read that file’s content and pass it through to the client, via `readfile`. No need to use any actual GD-Lib/ image functions here.

Comment: I don't know why switching to readfile worked, but it did? Perhaps it had something to do with the content length as you suggested, but its working fine now! Thank you very much for your help and insight..

Comment: Hah, funny if that solved it already :-) If your pixel image is really just 1px by 1px in size, then creating a new PNG from it via the GD-Lib might add some “overhead”, I think it is not to good at handling images that tiny. Could be Windows Mail had an issue dealing with the ratio of actual image content to image meta data then, or something like that.